# rm -rf not working, not sure why

Tags: linux, shell

I run this line of code

```
rm -rf /var/www/html/manga/cache/Lucky_Man_1_Blast

drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 29 13:33 Lucky_Man_1_Blast
```

It is not able to delete the folder, I am using it under root power.

May I check what actually went wrong with my Linux command.

```
root@S1ND45:/var/www/html/manga/cache/Lucky_Man_1_Blast# pwd
/var/www/html/manga/cache/Lucky_Man_1_Blast
```

When I run the code, I went back to /var/www/html/system/cache  and check, it appear that the folder still exist there.

I thought `rm -rf` (the `-rf` option should be forcefully delete wasn't it)?

Comment: Are you aware that `/var/www/html/system/cache/Lucky_Man_1_Blast` and `/var/www/html/manga/cache/Lucky_Man_1_Blast` are not the same directory?

Comment: What command produced this output: `drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 29 13:33 Lucky_Man_1_Blast`?

Comment: Did `rm` produce any output? How did you check that the directory is still there? Did another processs recreate the directory between the removal and your check?

Comment: The `-f` commands means, roughly, "don't ask questions and don't report problems".  Don't use the `-r` option unless you intend to delete a directory and its whole contents.  It is dangerous to get sloppy with the `rm` command — know exactly what it means.  In case of doubt, use `rm -i` instead.  If the file you name doesn't exist, or cannot be removed, then the `-f` option doesn't report that.  If you want to know about errors, omit the `-f` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're inside the directory in the shell where you deleted it, it may not disappear until you navigate away from the directory. `pwd` will show you are still within the directory.

Comment: Indeed this is the answer. If deleted while you are still in it, the cache manager tends to hold it present until finally leaving.

Comment: What's the 'cache manager' in this context?